Who owns the copyright for photos of work I did?
I worked self employed for a contractor, I have used images of the work I did (the whole work was done by me).
He took the pictures but I have just shared them. Am I liable to have to take these pictures down?
I was not “employed” by said person. I pay my own tax and was wholly self employed.
I did all the work myself and he did non, so I thought as I built the garden rooms I could use them my self as it was my work? Where would this stand in court as he’s threatening legal action for using the pictures.

You need to speak to a solicitor. What is the complainant actually saying? I can't quite understand it - on what grounds is he claiming that you need to take down the photos? Your question is unclear - from the question itself, it sounds like "he" took the pictures, but you say in a comment below that you took the pictures. Also, be aware that I think you misunderstand what is meant by the term "employed"... maybe you weren't a (permanent) employee of the contractor, but as a paid sub-contractor, you were indeed employed to do the job.

As osullic says, if you were paid then the product or your work usually belongs to the person who paid you. That said, you could just ask permission to display the photos.

@EricS, but then the question is was OP paid to take photographs or were they just paid to build the garden room and made the photos on their own (with the property owner's permission)?

You've failed to specify the jurisdiction you are in, but in the vast majority of jurisdictions, copyright is owned by the person that took the photo, unless it was done as "work for hire" - i.e. the person was taking the photo as part of their employment, in which case the photo is likely to be owned by the employer.
Put bluntly - the photos are not your work, you have no right to them. Your best bet here is to apologise and hope that's the end of it.

I wasn’t employed by him, we had no contract, he didn’t pay my tax and I had no wage slip.
I also took a lot of the pictures myself and sent them him through WhatsApp for him to post on the internet. Would this stand in court that I was the original person who took the picture so I owned the copyright? Thanks

The pictures you took are yours. However, in some jurisdictions the owners of the property may object to pictures of their property being put online as it could be considered a breach of privacy. So unless the work is outdoors and visible from the street you should ask them permission.

Thank you. The owners are fine with it as it’s a garden room outside and every picture was took with permission from them. Thank you for you help
